# Sending data from activity to class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I need your help guys. I'm making a quiz but i'm stuck. I first of all got a Activity where you can choose between categories:

```
package com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit.library.UserFunctions;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;
    Button btnEuropa;
    Button btnAmerika;
    Button btnAfrika;
    Button btnAzie;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Dashboard Screen for the application
         * */        
        // Check login status in database
        userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
        if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
            setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
            btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
            btnEuropa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEuropa);
            btnAmerika = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAmerika);
            btnAfrika = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAfrika);
            btnAzie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAzie);

            btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                    Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                    login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(login);
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                    finish();
                }
            });
            btnEuropa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    start.putExtra("continent","europa");
                    startActivity(start);
                    // Closing dashboard screen
                    finish();
                }
            });
            btnAmerika.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        start.putExtra("continent","amerika");
        startActivity(start);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }
});
btnAfrika.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        start.putExtra("continent","afrika");
        startActivity(start);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }
});
btnAzie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent start = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        start.putExtra("continent","azie");
        startActivity(start);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }
}); 


        }else{
            // user is not logged in show login screen
            Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(login);
            // Closing dashboard screen
            finish();
        }




    }
}
```

And then I go to the quiz = MainActivity. I send an intent so my MainAcitivty knows which category it is:

```
package com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit;
import java.util.List;

import com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit.library.UserFunctions;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    Button btnLogout;
    List<Vragen> quesList;
    int score=0;
    int qid=0;
    Vragen currentQ;
    TextView txtVraag;
    RadioButton rda, rdb, rdc;
    Button butVolgende;
    String value;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
         value = extras.getString("continent");
        }



        DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
        quesList=db.getAllQuestions();
        currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
        txtVraag=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtVraag);
        rda=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.antwoord1);
        rdb=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.antwoord2);
        rdc=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.antwoord3);
        butVolgende=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnVolgende);
        setQuestionView();
        butVolgende.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     

            public void onClick(View v) {
                RadioGroup grp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.grpAntwoord);
                RadioButton answer=(RadioButton)findViewById(grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                Log.d("yourans", currentQ.getANSWER()+" "+answer.getText());
                if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
                {
                    score++;
                    Log.d("score", "Your score"+score);
                }
                if(qid<10){     
                    currentQ=quesList.get(qid);
                    setQuestionView();
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putInt("score", score); //Your score
                    intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void setQuestionView()
    {
        txtVraag.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        qid++;
    }
}
```

But as for the questions themselves they are in the class DBHelper:

```
package com.laurenswuytsjordipapen.cultural.pursuit;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DbQuiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
                +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);        
        addQuestions();
        //db.close();
    }
        private void addQuestions()
    {

        Vragen q1=new Vragen("Op welke hooglanden draven er wilde rendieren rond in Groot Brittanie?","Andes gebergte", "Schotse hooglanden", "Britse hooglanden", "Schotse hooglanden");
        this.addVraag(q1);
        Vragen q2=new Vragen("In welke Italiaanse stad zijn de Ponte Vechio en het Palazzo Medici belangrijke bezienswaardigheden??", "Milan", "Rome", "Firenze", "Firenze");
        this.addVraag(q2);
        Vragen q3=new Vragen("Wat is het favoriete land van een Gallomaan?","Frankrijk", "Egypte", "Duitsland", "Frankrijk");
        this.addVraag(q3);
        Vragen q4=new Vragen("Welke Europese hoofdstad is net zoals Rome op zeven heuvels gebouwd?", "Brussel", "Parijs", "Rome", "Brussel");
        this.addVraag(q4);
        Vragen q5=new Vragen("Wat is naast Vaticaanstad, Monaco, San Marino en Andorra het vijfde Europese ministaatje?","Corsica", "Luxemburg", "Lichtenstein", "Lichtenstein");
        this.addVraag(q5);
        Vragen q6=new Vragen("Aan welke golf ligt de kuststreek tussen Marseille en Perpignan?", "Golf van Frankrijk", "Golf van Lyon", "Middellandse zee", "Golf van Lyon");
        this.addVraag(q6);
        Vragen q7=new Vragen("Welke nationaliteit heeft hordeloper Jonathan N Senga?","Belgische", "Canadees", "Ganees", "Belgische");
        this.addVraag(q7);
        Vragen q8=new Vragen("Welke munt werd de Alpendollar genoemd?", "Oostenrijkse Shilling", "Bulgaarse Lef", "Franse Frank", "Oostenrijkse Shilling");
        this.addVraag(q8);
        Vragen q9=new Vragen("Aan welke natie gaf Zanzibar zich in 1896 over na exact 38 minuten oorlog voeren?","Engeland", "China", "Amerika", "Engeland");
        this.addVraag(q9);
        Vragen q10=new Vragen("Welke stad telde als eerste in de geschiedenis meer dan 1 miljoen inwoners?", "Rome", "Tokyo", "Kopenhagen", "Rome");
        this.addVraag(q10);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addVraag(Vragen quest) {
        //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION()); 
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        // Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);        
    }
    public List<Vragen> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Vragen> quesList = new ArrayList<Vragen>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Vragen quest = new Vragen();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        // return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
    public int rowcount()
    {
        int row=0;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        row=cursor.getCount();
        return row;
    }
}
```

I need to somehow put the intent that I got in my Mainativity to my class DBHelper. So I can make if and else clausules for my questions. Does anybody know how I can send the intent "continent" from my MainActivity to my DbHelper :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can send the selected continent value through constructor of DBHelper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can send that data. I think that the best solution is giving it in `DBHelper` constructor.